# Google Analytics site search catagory parameter

Tags: search, google-analytics, parameters, categories

How can I use my site's search string with GA's site search 'category parameter'?

/access-shop/product-search/#?PageSize=10&SortBy=_score&Descending&CurrentPageNumber=1&Keyword=test

I have identified 'Keyword' as the 'query parameter' and tried '/access-shop/' as the category, but GA reports *category (not set)*.

What I'm attempting is to get reports of what search terms are being used in various search pages. We have four distinct search areas on the site.

[image: GA site search category]

Thanks heaps!

Comment: I just noticed, when I look at my own URL, that 'access-shop' or 'product-search' is not part of the query string. GA may not be looking there. What else is possible?

Answer (score 0):

On the query parameters, Keyword should be separated by a coma instead of a dot.

Comment: Well spotted and thanks Ana Gomez. I've updated the parameters.